# how can i make cucumber test on multiple 'a' tag with image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

this is my view code where i have make multiple 'a' tag and want to test third element from li. and we can uniquely identified with offer id as per below code ...

```
<div class="search_data_outer_div">
  <ul>
   <li class="small_preview">
     <div class="image_area">
       <a href="/offer/show/334">
     </div>
     <span>
       <span class="artist_name">Artist 1</span>
       <span class="remaining_time">Remaining Time: 7 days</span>
       <i id="334" class="icon-remove pointer" style="position:absolute;right:0;display:none;"></i>
    </span>
  </li>
```

and i have tried make one step defination ... it is working fine with cucumber but when execute with selenium (WebDriver) then page not open after click.

```
Scenario:    
When I press third offer
Then I should see "YOUR OFFER"
```

and its step defination file

```
When /^I press third offer$/ do
  page.execute_script %Q{ $(".search_data_outer_div ul li .image_area a").eq(2).click(); }
end
```

let me know right solution if anybody can help

thanks

Answer (score 0):

IIRC CSS style selectors have issues with some version of Web Driver.  Ideally you'd have PageObject variables set up for this so you're not using raw webdriver code in your steps but something like this should work:

```
browser.div( :class => 'search_data_outer_div').div( :class => 'image_area').links.first.click
```